# Cant find lib of mysql cpp connector

Tags: mysql, libraries

I cant find that driver. I installed it 10 times via `libmysqlcppconn-dev_8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb`.

Mysql Workbench and Server are working...

I need it to link in my cmakeLists....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: @N0rbert No.. My linker is does not find shared object for mysql.h[eaders]...

Comment: Then please add more details to the question with exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

For missed *mysql.h* header install [other package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=include%2Fmysql%2Fmysql.h&searchon=contents) by

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```